# Move pdf files from one library to folder within library in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2012

I want to move files from the Library into its folder (Which is in the same library). How can I do this using sharepiont Designer 2013

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

[image]

With foldername being the folder you want to move the item to.

If it fails, verify that you are choosing the correct “Name” (not 'for use in forms' or 'linked to document with edit menu' value and that you do not have a ”/ ” before the folder name in the string builder.

Comment: I want to do this using SPD 2013 workflow not copy paste

Comment: I updated the answer